# Swift mysqlのデータを表示

Tags: swift, php

Swiftでmysqlのデータを表示するには.text=なににすればいいですか？

Comment: 「text=」とはどういう意味でしょうか？またPHPタグが入っていますがPHPは関係していますか？

Comment: .text= です mysqlのカラムのデータを表示するcellのテキストラベルのパラメーターcell.text= ということです